# How do I automatically set the version of my software in package.json with each release?

Tags: angular, package.json

I'm using Angular, version 12.2.

I'd like to increment the version of my software, as you can see in [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtqDe.png), with each release of my software. It's tedious to go into this file and edit the 'version' value, with each release. It would be great to have this version value automatically increment with each push into main branch (release branch).

In short, I'd like to automatically increment the package.json version number, with each push into main branch.

Thanks!

Comment: Script it. `npm version major | minor | patch` does that for you

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. So what would the workflow be in practice? 1. Make an edit on test branch, commit changes, merge branch into main, run npm version minor && npm version patch after pushing this main branch?

Comment: It depends of your tooling (do you have a jenkins ?) and workflow (maybe you use Git flow ?) but the place for it is either during the merge phase or in a dedicated "release script" that could also be an alias for `npm version minor && git commit -m "blabla" && git push`. I would not do it too often though as it can clutter your git history with version commits.

Comment: https://semver.org/ and https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow